# Flutter web passwordless login does not trigger auth state change

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-web

I am trying to implement password-less login in flutter web app. I used a `StreamBuilder` widget to monitor Auth State.

```
          child: StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              print("AuthStateChanged");
              print(snapshot.connectionState);
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
                print("Connection Active");
                FirebaseUser user = snapshot.data;
                if (user == null) {
                  return LoginPage();
                }
                return LoggedIn();
              } else {
                print("Connection Inactive"); //Connection Inactive, show error dialog
                return Text("***");
              }
            },
          ),
```

I have created a dynamic link in firebase, `https://mypwakk.page.link/6SuK` which points to an html asking the user to go back to the app.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sign in via email</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>You now have signed in.</h1>
      <p>Go back to the same device you opened the app from and continue using the app as an authenticated user.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then the signin link was sent using `FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndLink()`

When the link in the email was received, I clicked it and it did take me to the html page. At this point I expected the auth state will be changed in my StreamBuilder and the handler print debug message. But I don't see anything printed on the console.

Am I missing something? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the user was signed in to a different instance of the app, then only *that* instance will be signed in. To ensure that your `onAuthStateChanged` fires, make sure the link is opened in the app instance that contains the `FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged` listener.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen, it is the same instance. It was open in chrome while email was sent and the link was clicked.

Comment: Hmmm... I'd expect the `onAuthStateChanged` to fire in that case, but must admit I've never tried with Flutter Web. If you force a check of `currentUser` is the auth state actually picked up there? If so, it'd at least just be an issue with the listener.

Comment: Added a button with ```onPressed: () async {
          FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
          print(user.toString());
        }```, getting ```null```. So it is not an issue with listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation with dynamic link I have resolved this issue.

What I did wrong is,

- Created a html page to handle link click.
- Created a dynamic link domain.
- Created a dynamic link that points to html page url.
- Provided the dynamic link as the `url` parameter to `actionCodeSettings` when I sent the email link.

What I should have done,

- Create a html page to handle link click. Add java-script handler to perform the click verification and login process.
- Create a dynamic link domain.
- Provide the html page url as the `url` parameter and the dynamic link domain as `dynamicLinkDomain` parameter to `actionCodeSettings` when I sent the email link.

Check, https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth#completing_sign-in_in_a_web_page. The documentation does specify the process but coming from flutter land,  translating this to flutter web target was somewhat obscure to me. Hopefully there will be some clear sample code for flutter web target available in future.

Comment: Have you successfully implemented a Passwordless email sign in with Flutter Web?

Comment: Do we have any news? Does this actually work or is it just a java-script solution? Up to now I have not seen any example.